# Powershell Send-MailMessage Error

Tags: powershell

Unable to get Send-MailMessage to work with an office365 email, so now trying with gmail but still not working.

Brings up error:Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 
Authentication Required.

Have browsed a lot of similar send-mail errors and tried a number of suggestions

- Turned on "Use less secure Apps" in gmail security settings
- Tried removing useSSL
- Double checked gmail address and password

Being very new at powershell, can someone point me in the right direction? Code below:

```
 $From = "example@gmail.com"
 $To = "SomeOtherAddress@whatever.com"
 $Subject = "Here's the Email Subject"
 $Body = "This is what I want to say"
 $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
 $SMTPPort = "587"
 Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define an object and assign the return value from `Get-Credential` to it

like so:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $cred
```

Source/further info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-6

Comment: Thanks @Kristian, especially for the source link. Pointed me in the right direction to refine the script.